# Question about upper bounds

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a$ is an upper bound for the real zeros of the polynomial $P$, then $-a$ is necessarily a lower bound for the real zeros of $P$.

Is this true?

I think it is false because if we divide $P(x)$ by $x-a$ (with a < 0) this would already be different. If $a$ is $-a$ it would be $x+a$ which is greater than 0. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=1$ and consider the polynomial $(x-1)(x+3)$.

Answer (score 2):

You are right that it is false, but an easy way to see it is to assume that the upper bound $a$ is negative. Then $-a$ is positive and obviously can't be a lower bound. However even if $a$ is positive then it is still false. Just take the polynomial $(x-1)(x+2)$.

Answer (score 2):

Think about $x(x+2)$, the upper bound is 0, clearly -0 isn't the lower bound.